# Как удалить скрипт который генерирует хост или удалять текст ссылки которую генерирует хост

Tags: javascript, c#, веб-программирование, hosting, asp

Загрузил сайт на ASP MVC на хост и возникла проблема, что при каждом возврате html файла с сервера, хост автоматически добавляет свою ссылку. При подгрузке данных на страницу это создает проблемы. Можно ли как-то удалить этот скрип?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал удалять ссылку, т.к. вы на бесплатный тариф поставили. Могут ваш аккаунт заблокировать... Читайте правила сервиса прежде чем удалять

Comment: Купите платный тариф. На бесплатных тарифах цена - как раз эта ссылка от хостера и вполне возможно, что правилами хостер запрещает удаление/модификацию этой ссылки и вас могут просто выкинуть с хостинга, если бот со временем обнаружит её отсутствие. Все приведённые ответы -- техничекие способы обхода, которые могут окааться нелегальными с юридической точки зрения и вы только подставляете себя таким образом.

Answer (score 0):

Да, воспользуйтесь css, например так

```
    center > a{
      display: none;
    }
```

Если предоставите ссылку или код который на выходе, то смогу более точно сказать что и куда прописать. А так думаю смысл понятен

Comment: К сожаление там нет никаких классов. Просто <a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a> обернутый в center

Comment: Обновил стиль, теперь ссылка должна пропасть если его применить ко всем страницам где она появляется

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы также можете попробовать удалить этот элемент с помощью селектора a[href="somee.com"].
Для теста, прямо из консоли хрома ввести `document.querySelector("a[href='somee.com']").remove()`